# gen_fsm initial state, sending event to it on spawning

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

If I want to always send an event to the initial state of a gen_fsm when I have spawned it, where should I put that function call? Right after start_link or from the process that invoked start_link in the first place. Are there any best practices here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to alter the state of the FSM after you start it, you might simply implement the init function for your state machine:

Reading from: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_fsm.html#Module:init-1

> Whenever a gen_fsm is started using
>   gen_fsm:start/3,4 or
>   gen_fsm:start_link/3,4, this function
>   is called by the new process to
>   initialize.
>
> Args is the Args argument provided to
>   the start function.
>
> If initialization is successful, the
>   function should return
>   {ok,StateName,StateData},
>   {ok,StateName,StateData,Timeout} or
>   {ok,StateName,StateData,hibernate},
>   where StateName is the initial state
>   name and StateData the initial state
>   data of the gen_fsm.

Also, using the init function, you're sure about the atomicity of the two functions (start_link and init). They will both succeed or fail.

Comment: The main thing isn't that I want to alter the state, I want to execute the code in the initial state and then change to the next state. Should I just make the init function return a timeout value of 0 as proposed in answer below?

Comment: When you start the gen_fsm with the start_link function, the state is passed to the init function. You can then execute your code there and, if needed, update the state, which will be available for the rest of the gen_fsm lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I thik it is right to send first event from the process invoking FSM start function. Or return timeout = 0 from init/1 and handle 'timeout' event in the initial state.

On the other hand, it makes races possible if your gen_fsm is a rgistered process. If that is the case I would send message to the gen_fsm process PID from init/1 befor registering.

Comment: Would a timeout value of 0 in the init function lead to potential race conditions? Or did you mean that calling from the process that started the FSM could lead to race conditions?

Comment: Both of them lead to race conditions if FSM process was registered before start_link returns.